# Drag and Drop from Silverlight OOB to another App

Tags: user-controls, drag-and-drop, silverlight-5.0

Well, here is another question that I think has been answered, but I need to ask it anyway. Is it possible to create a customized Silverlight 5 control that can be dragged from one application to another? The behavior I would like to emulate is like the Spy++ Crosshair Icon.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please ... can anyone shed some light on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much research and deliberation, we abandoned the idea of using Silverlight to achieve our goal. The resulting application is a Windows Forms desktop application.

Since no one here decided to help answering this particular question, I will answer it with this: It is not possible to use Silverlight to create a control that you can drag over to an external application and find the Window Handle information for that external app.

Comment: Silverlight supports messaging between apps so you could simulate the drag-drop that way. Problem is that when cursor moved out of the 1st app you wouldn't be able to update it yourself anymore unless maybe you use mouse capturing feature of Silverlight (and of course use one of the standard mouse cursors)